# How to use local chdir in vim by default

Tags: vim, configuration, settings

With vim, can I change the default behaviour of `:cd` to run `:lcd` without creating a new command? That just feels a bit hacky, and it seems like there'd be a global setting for this kind of thing.

#### Background

- The `:cd` command changes the working directory of vim.
- The `:lcd` command only changes this for the current buffer.

Comment: Hacky? It sounds less hacky than overriding the meaning of `cd`! ;-)

Comment: `:lcd` is for current window, not for buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Such a setting would be highly confusing for unsuspecting users, wouldn't it?! If you want to have `:lcd`, you have to use that command. There are plugins like [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) that let you redefine `:cd` -- but only for interactive use, not in plugins (who might break with such a change, anyway).

Another option is a (rather trivial) change to the source code, and compiling your own version of Vim. But what's so bad about `:lcd`?!

PS: `:lcd` is local to the current *window*, not the current buffer. This matters when you `:edit` a different buffer in a window.

Answer (score 0):

Would `set autochdir` do what you want or did I completely misunderstand your question?